# Is there any built-in function like entry.get() in r?

Tags: r

Hi I am now tring to make searching code, and want to search what i want to get by entering into entry. But I am not sure if there is also built-in function like entry.get which is from python in r. This is the code I am trying.

```r
function() {
    tt<- tktoplevel()
    lbl <- tklabel(tt, text="GUI PRACTICE")
    tkpack(lbl)
    
    exit <- function() {
        tkdestroy(tt)
    }
    srch <- function() {
        chn<-as.matrix(read.delim("12.txt"))
        tkinsert(txt, "0.0", grep("cho", chn, value=TRUE))
        
    }
    srch.but <-tkbutton(tt, text="Search", command=srch)
    e.srch <-tkentry(tt, width=20)
    tkpack(e.srch, srch.but)
    
    txt <- tktext(tt, height=10)
    tkpack(txt)
    
    but<-tkbutton(tt, text="Exit", command=exit)
    tkpack(but)
}
```

Comment: Do you mean `tkentrycget`?

Comment: @r2evans sorry for late answer. yes it is! there is not many information about tcl/tk for r... so I coudn't find it. can it be also used like entry.get() in python?

Comment: I don't use `tcltk`, to be honest, so I can't really help. I believe that it is structured very similarly, and since `tcltk::tkentrycget` is really just calling TCL's `entrycget` directly, I'd think it should behave identically to it.